# How to compare elements of a generic type

Tags: java, stack, comparator, comparable

I have a class `MinStack<T>` which takes several different types. I understand that the `Comparable` interface is used to compare instances of the same type. Do I need to write a separate `compareTo()` method for each type that may be passed to my data structure? If not what would the `compareTo` method look like? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MinStack<T> implements Comparable<T> {

private ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<T> min = new ArrayList<T>();

@Override
public int compareTo(T o) {
    return this.compareTo(o);
}

public void push(T x) {

    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        a.add(x);
        min.add(x);
    } else if (!a.isEmpty()) {
        a.add(x);
        int r = x.compareTo(min.get(min.size()-1));
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an error saying "cannot resolve method compareTo(T)"

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  Personally, I'd let each class implement its own `CompareTo()`.

Comment: compareTo is the default comparison algorithm, if you have a Person class, you might want to compare by Age as default dimension, but, for a specific application you might want to not compare by age but by income, in that case use a Comparator, which is a external class.
Is really up to you, and part of your design. For example, a Vehicle could compare by speed, so, if you compare a car to a Bicycle, it will use that dimension, but if you compare two Cars, you might want to compare by HorsePower, so, override the compareTo so that if both are Cars, use that dimension, if not, use max speed.

Comment: I'm trying to compare values to return the min value stored in the data structure. The MinStack<T> accepts all kinds of Objects.

Comment: They must follow some structure, how do you compare an Integer with a String? is 2 > "Hi" ?

Comment: I meant do i need several different compareTo methods for the different types or is there a way to do so with 1 method.

Comment: Sorry. Some of the code snippet got cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is for the elements in your `MinStack` to be comparable, not the stacks themselves. To do this, you need to impose `Comparable` as a [type bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) on your parametric type. The following rewrite of your code compiles fine and should do what you want:

```
public class MinStack<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<T> min = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void push(T x) {

        if (a.isEmpty()) {
            a.add(x);
            min.add(x);
        } else if (!a.isEmpty()) {
            a.add(x);
            int r = x.compareTo(min.get(min.size()-1));
        }
    }
}
```